# Allowing Kind to render elements in other components gives me a white screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render the child elements inside the AuthProvider component. However, this doesn't work. I just get a white screen. If I remove the AuthProvider component surrounding the StackNavigator, then everything works. So it has something to do with the surrounding component and its children.

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthProvider from "./hooks/AuthProvider";
import StackNavigator from "./StackNavigator";

export default function App() {
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
   <AuthProvider>
     <StackNavigator></StackNavigator>
   </AuthProvider>
 </NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

AuthProvider.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
 return <View>{children}</View>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

StackNavigator.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { store, persistor } from "./redux/store.js";
import TabNavigator from "./TabNavigator.js";
import SingleArticel from "./pages/SingleArticel.js";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Navigator" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SingleArticel" component={SingleArticel} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
   </PersistGate>
   </Provider>
   );
 };

export default StackNavigator;
```

Comment: Try putting the AuthProvider outside of the NavigationContainer. NavigationContainer should only contain Screens and other navigators. Also make sure that the View has flex:1 so that the NavigationContainer can be visible inside AuthProvider. Your Provider and PersistGate should also be outside the NavigationContainer as far as I know.